# Android newbie - socket client without thread

Tags: java, android

I'd like to finalize a very simple app: send a TCP packet to a server.
Server answer, for the moment does not matter.

So, I write a very simple class where I create a socket, send the message and then, close the socket.

The app crash in `s.send(msg.serialized);` and I do not understand why.

Code in myActivity:

```
        final TcpSender s = new TcpSender();

        switch (tab_ID) {
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

                //----- btn_BotolaUp
                final ToggleButton btn_light = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_light);
                btn_light.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        String toastmessage;

                        if (isChecked) {
                            msg.serialize("Identifier", "ON", "datafield1", "datafield2");
                            toastmessage = "Light ON";
                        } else {
                            msg.serialize("Identifier", "OFF", "datafield1", "datafield2");
                            toastmessage = "Light OFF";
                        }

                        s.send(msg.serialized);
                        Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), toastmessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            case.... 
                etc
```

TcpSender Class is defined as follow:

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TcpSender {
Socket socket;

public boolean send(String messagetosend) {

    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 10000);
        Log.d("Net", "Socket created");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        Log.d("Net", "PrintWriter out");

        out.print(messagetosend);
        Log.d("Net", "Message: " + messagetosend + " ->sent");
        socket.close();
        Log.d("Net", "Socket closed");

    } catch (UnknownHostException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Net", "UnknownHostException err");
        return (false);
    } catch (IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Net","IOException err");
        return (false);
    }

    Log.d("Net","send successful!");
    return (true);
}

}
```

Could someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: In android generally you get a compile error for UrlConnection and any other network operation on main thread. I think this also falls in same category. Try doing this in a thread

Comment: What is the exception being thrown in logcat?

Comment: is it network on main thread exception?

Comment: @RahulTiwari I'm pretty sure you get a runtime android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException not a compile error but you are probably correct that that is the root of OP's problem.

Comment: @JJF yes you are correct but  I remember seeing eclipse showing red error mark few years back when tried making urlconnection in onCreate method.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is that you are going to need a separate thread if you want to do network operations.  Android does not allow network operations on your app's main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Google prevents you from using main thread for the network tasks, and here is the reason:

> Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations on a separate thread from the UI. The `AsyncTask` class provides one of the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread.

and make sure the proper permissions are included in manifest.

you may figure out this issue and learn more with the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask).

Comment: So, if I have well understood, I have to create socket, send packet and close socket inside the same separate task... In this way, I'll create a new task ( new connectTask().execute(""); ) everytime I need to send a packet... is it ok ? I deduce that the task, once terminated, will be killed by garbage ? Is it OK ?